# Http Status 405 Request Method 'POST' not supported when using reverse proxy

Tags: java, spring, apache, tomcat, reverse-proxy

I set up a simple Spring Java(1.8) application on Tomcat 8 which consists of a web form and java controller. All my controller  methods work fine when I connect directly to  web application through Tomcat. However when I use a reverse proxy using Apache 2.4, the POST methods no longer work and return with a 405 error. Both Tomcat and Apache are running in the same VM. I am using Ubuntu 14.0.4.  With the reverse proxy, I am able to load the initial page which uses a controller method annotated in the following:
**@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "/upload").**
But all my POST methods fail with the following:

1. I get the following message in my java logs:
   **o.s.web.servlet.PageNotFound             : Request method 'POST' not supported**
2. In my browser console, I see the following in the console. Note the **Allow:HEAD, GET** does not appear when I do not use the reverse proxy.

> ```
> Request URL:http://192.168.9.131/file-upload/logout
> Request Method:POST
> Status Code:405 Method Not Allowed
> Remote Address:192.168.9.131:80
> Response Headers
> view source
> Allow:HEAD, GET
> Connection:Keep-Alive
> Content-Language:en-US
> Content-Length:338
> Content-Type:text/html;charset=UTF-8
> Date:Wed, 13 Jul 2016 12:28:35 GMT
> Keep-Alive:timeout=5, max=99
> Server:Apache-Coyote/1.1
>
> Request Headers                     
> Accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
> Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
> Cache-Control:max-age=0 Connection:keep-alive Content-Length:0
> Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded
> Cookie:JSESSIONID=F41DA5B69E6AE49C710906C4591F2445 Host:192.168.9.131
> Origin:http://192.168.9.131 Referer:http://192.168.9.131/
> Upgrade-Insecure-Requests:1 User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1;
>   WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.103
>   Safari/537.36
> ```

Both the proxy_http and proxy modules are enabled. I put the following in my Apache 2 (version 2.4.7) Virtual Host file:

```
    ServerAdmin admin@localhost
ServerName www.example.com
    ServerAlias deanhm.com
     ProxyPreserveHost On
     ProxyRequests off
    ProxyPass / http://www.example.com:8081/file-upload/upload
    ProxyPassReverse / http://www.example.com:8081/file-upload/upload
```

Require all granted

I added the following in the server.xml of Tomcat

```
   **<Connector connectionTimeout="20000" port="8081" protocol="HTTP/1.1" redirectPort="8443"
    scheme="http" proxyName="deanhm.com" proxyPort="80"/>**
```

An example(simplest) of the controller methods that I cannot access: Note when debugging I do not enter the method.

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = "/logout")
    public String handleLogout(HttpSession session, HttpServletRequest    request) {

        session.setAttribute("LogoutMessage", "You have logged out!");

        System.out.println(" My id is " + request.getHeader("HTTP_UID"));

        try {
            logoutOpenAM(request);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return "logout";
    }
```

The html page snippet which calls the logout is:

```html
<div>
     <form method="POST" action="/file-upload/logout">
      <input type="submit" value="Logout" />
     </form>
</div>
```

Currently I am running my Tomcat through Eclipse.

Below is a snippet from my POM file.

```
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.3.RELEASE</version>
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: I found the problem.  I had to tweak the URL's in the Virtual Host config file and my java application.    ProxyPass / http://www.example.com:8081/file-upload/
 ProxyPassReverse / http://www.example.com:8081/file-upload/